# Call super().__init__() in classes derived from `object`?

Tags: python

The Python [documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__init__#object.__init__) says that the `__init__` method of each class is responsible for initializing its super class.  But for new-style classes, the ultimate base class is `object`.  Doing `dir(object)` shows that `object` itself has an `__init__` method and could potentially be initialized.  Is there any reason to do that?

I'm inclined to do it for consistency and (slightly) easier refactoring of the class heirarchy, but I wonder if it's strictly necessary or is considered best practice.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You don't *need* to initialize `object`; its `__init__` is a no-op. It's still good practice, though, as you might want to introduce an intermediate class in the hierarchy later on.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, do it.  It's a good habit to get into, and it doesn't hurt.

Answer (score 5):

IMHO it doesn't make any sense at all.

1. It makes you double check the inheritance to realize that it does nothing
2. It's the same as adding a `pass` statement with the overhead of function call.
3. Quoting the zen: `Although practicality beats purity.`
4. Python 3 doesn't require you to declare `object` as super class.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, and [there is a reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277367/how-does-pythons-super-work-with-multiple-inheritance) why you should do it.

If you ever need to use multi inheritance, python's C3 method resolution order (MRO) will not call all your `__init__()` base classes.